# django DoesNotExist admin panel good

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have an issue with the try except block.
So the admin panel shows entry into the tables but when I run the following piece of code, it goes in the exception handling part . So, I added prints in the try and except parts, it is hitting both blocks together. What could be the issue or how can  I debug it ?

```
def mypark(request):
    context_dict = {}
    u = request.user
    checked_in_friends = []
   try:
        visitors = Owner.objects.exclude(user=request.user).filter(checked_in=True).count()
        current = Owner.objects.get(user=u)
        friends = Friendship.objects.filter(Q(from_friend = u) | Q(to_friend = u))
        
    except Owner.DoesNotExist:
        print(visitors)
        visitors = None
```

The code hits the except part and prints the value of visitors as if it exists but then why it calculates that the Owner does not exist , I do not understand.

Comment: What is `u`? It might be the culprit of this problem.

Comment: Apparently you don't have an `Owner` instance that satisfies the condition `user=u`. What is `u`?

Comment: u is the current user. I just added in code showing the part of code or function definition where the try and except is contained in. Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you certainly have data that has `u` as user.

Comment: The admin panel does show the owner objects

Comment: Maybe user is not logged in.